# Data Binding from Android project to ViewModel

Tags: android, xamarin, data-binding, xamarin.forms

I am trying to get list of available wifi network and display it in a list view. In PCL project, i created an interface 'IWifiService'.

```
 public interface IWifiService
{
    void GetWifiList();
}
```

In android project a class WifiService to get all networks list.

```
[assembly:Dependency(typeof(WifiService))]
namespace WifiConnectivity.Droid.WifiService
{
public class WifiService : IWifiService
{
    private static WifiManager wifi;
    private WifiReceiver wifiReceiver;
    public static List<string> WiFiNetworks;

    public void GetWifiList()
    {
        WiFiNetworks = new List<string>();
        var context = Android.App.Application.Context;
        wifi = (WifiManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.WifiService);
        wifiReceiver = new WifiReceiver();
        context.RegisterReceiver(wifiReceiver, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.ScanResultsAvailableAction));
        wifi.StartScan();

    }

    public class WifiReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
    {
        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            IList<ScanResult> scanWifiNetworks = wifi.ScanResults;
            foreach(ScanResult wifinetwork in scanWifiNetworks)
            {
                WiFiNetworks.Add(wifinetwork.Ssid);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

And from ViewModel i am calling a Dependency Service like this:

```
 var service = DependencyService.Get<IWifiService>();
        service.GetWifiList();
```

Now the class WifiReceiver cannot return anything, so i am not being able to get those list of networks in my ViewModel. How can i get this list into my ViewModel?

Comment: It won't because you have the `void` return type in `IWifiService`.

Comment: FYI: WifiManager.StartScan() was deprecated in Pie...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you return a List in your GetWifiList method so the interface looks something like this:

```
 public interface IWifiService
 {
    void GetWifiList(Action<List<string>> action);
 }
```

And then your GetWifiList method will look like this:

```
public static Action<List<string>> CallBackAction;

public void GetWifiList(Action<List<string>> callBackMethod)
{
    WiFiNetworks = new List<string>();
    var context = Android.App.Application.Context;
    wifi = (WifiManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.WifiService);
    wifiReceiver = new WifiReceiver();
    context.RegisterReceiver(wifiReceiver, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.ScanResultsAvailableAction));
    wifi.StartScan();
    CallBackAction= callBackMethod;
}
```

And then in your OnRecieve method, you execute the callback method:

```
public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        IList<ScanResult> scanWifiNetworks = wifi.ScanResults;
        foreach(ScanResult wifinetwork in scanWifiNetworks)
        {
            WiFiNetworks.Add(wifinetwork.Ssid);
        }
        CallBackAction(WiFiNetworks);
    }
```

And now the most important part of the callback method and what to pass as your argument:

A System.Action is basically a method reference where you pass the name of your call back method something like below:

```
    var service = DependencyService.Get<IWifiService>();
    service.GetWifiList(MyCallBackAction);
```

Where MyCallBackAction is as below:

```
   public void MyCallBackAction(List<string> wifiNetworks)
   {
    // this method will be called every time you get a callback at OnRecieve
   }
```

Comment: Thanks @G.hakim I will try this. and let you know if it works

Comment: Sure let me know